# Redirecting to a different domain with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

how would i redirect all requests to a different domain that is pointing at the same server via htaccess.

I have

domain.com
domain.se
domain.dk

I only have SSL for domain.com, so i would prefer all requests to .se and .dk to be redirect to:

se.domain.com
dk.domain.com

I have attempted but i failed, it wrote the request like this

domain.se/http://se.domain.com

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.se [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://se.domain.com [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.(se|dk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```